# Blender 3D-View: Objects aspect ratio off

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I'm using Blender 2.73a at the default startup with the cube.

Using Perspective or Ortho, the length and width of the Cube is clearly dependent on the current aspect ratio of the Element HDTV elefw231 screen that I'm using.

If I set the objects scale I can counter and the cube looks like a cube and not rectangular.

Of course then I have to remove it. This is on my ATI Radeon HD 4650 Graphics. My Laptop is not like this.

Comment: That is very weird, but I think the distortion is something you should fix at the operating system.

Comment: Setting a non-native resolution can cause this distortion. For HDTV I expect you want 1920x1080 or 1280x720 - change it in your monitor resolution system control panel.

Comment: my monitor apparently doesnt support a native resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the resolution to 1366 x 768 pixel, your (weird) screen's native one, if your graphics card allows it.

Comment: ATI Radeon HD 4650.  Unfortunately does not support this mode. But I feel you are probably correct.   Thank you all for your time.

Comment: I bought a new video card, and your answer solved my problem